# Mapping JSON to POJO not working

Tags: json, spring, pojo

I have a spring MVC project,in the controller i have the following method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = IdentityServiceURIConstants.CREATE_NEW_USER, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {----}
```

this method receives a JSON object which is supposed to represent the user object.

My problem is that the fields in the user object are not identical to those received in the JSON object.

Example: first name is `First_Name` in JSON and `firstName` in object, hence, the mapping is not working.

Do u have any idea on how to solve this problem, given that i cant edit neither the user object nor the JSONobject

Answer (score 2):

You can use **@JsonProperty** to name your java class property to the json key name like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class User {

    @JsonProperty("FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    // getters & Setters methods
}
```

and your json will be something like this:

```
{
    "FIRST_NAME": "first name",
    "SECOND_NAME": "second name"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i know this, but as i told you i don't have access to the user object class to annotate its fields

Comment: if you don't have control on Java object, then the json string that you pass to the controller method should be the way the User object is defined. Your json should have the key names identical to the property names in your POJO like **{"firstName":"first name", "secondName":"second name"}**

Comment: @PrasadKhode, Thanks man, your answer really works. I was unable to map the JSON with class. By using your answer it started mapping it. Really big fat thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a DTO class.

```
class UserDTO{
      private User user;

      // use getter setter to extract data from object 
}
```